# How to print subsets (power sets) of an array consisting all integers in lexicographic order in c language?

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, iteration

> > Given an array of unique integer elements, print all the subsets of the given array in lexicographical order.
> >
> > Input Format
> >
> > First line of input contains T - number of test cases. Its followed by 2T lines, the first line contains N - the size of the array and
> >     second line contains the elements of the array.
> >
> > Constraints
> >
> > 1 <= T <= 100
> >
> > 1 <= N <= 10
> >
> > 0 <= A[i] <= 100
> >
> > Output Format
> >
> > For each test case, print the subsets of the given array in lexicographical order, separated by new line. Print an extra newline
> >     between output of different test cases.

```
void solve()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    merge_sort(a,0,n-1);//for sorting, not given here
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<n);i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((i&(1<<j))>0)
                printf("%d ",a[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

> ```
> What shall I do after this should I use a 2d array? if so how?
> >
> > Sample Input 0
> > 
> > 3(no.of test cases)
> >
> > 3(size)
> >
> > 5 15 3(input elements)
> > 
> > 2
> > 
> >57 96
> >
> > 4
> >
> >3 15 8 23
> > 
> > 
> >## Expected output## 
>
> 3 
> 3 5  
> 3 5 15  
> 3 15  
> 5  
> 5 15 
> 15 
>
> 57
> 57 96  
> 96  
>
> 3  
> 3 8  
> 3 8 15  
> 3 8 15 23  
> 3 8 23  
> 3 15  
> 3 15 23  
> 3 23 
> 8  
> 8 15 
> 8 15 23  
> 8 23  
> 15  
> 15 23  
> 23
> ```

Comment: What is is the issue?

Comment: This question would be easier with recursion; set out a base case, _etc_.

Comment: @AMC I can't think of any logic in C language to sort the power set in a lexicographic fashion please help me

Comment: Have you tried breaking down the problem, writing pseudocode?

Comment: This looks like homework, so I won't provide the code, but you would need to come up with a recurrence. Sort the array, then, `R(A) = { { a_0, R(A - a_0) }, { R(A - a_0) } }` as long as `A` is not empty. Also, `A[i]` is not defined anywhere, but if it's the maximum in each set, then it's possible to do it without recursion easily using the [power set homomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set#Representing_subsets_as_functions); it becomes a counting problem.

Comment: Yes @AMC but I can't go any further after generating subsets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ANSWER TO THIS**

> > Without using recursion
> >
> > > this code can still be optimized any help in doing so will be greatly helpful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void solve();
void merge(int a[],int s,int e);
void merge_sort(int a[],int s,int e);
int indexSearcher(int a[],int b[],int h,int i);
int main() {
int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);/* This is for printing testcases*/
    while(t--)
    {
        solve();
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
    int compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
return(*(int*)a > *(int*)b);
}
void solve()
{
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n+1],main_a[n];
    a[n]=-1;



for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&main_a[i]);

}
qsort(main_a, n, sizeof(int), compare);//for sorting
    /* loading all the elements to another array so that it won't miss its original  
      sorted order and it is used as reference*/
    for(int e=0;e<n;e++){
        a[e]=main_a[e];
    }


int j=0;
int i=0;
for( j=0;j<n;j++){
for( i=0;i<=j;i++)
printf("%d ",a[i]);//This can be optimized also.
    printf("\n");
}
    a[i]=-1;// the invalid value is replaced by -1 every time
    int u=i;//assigning or updating u to last valid index every time

    while(a[0]!=main_a[n-1]){    
if(a[u-1]==main_a[n-1]) 
 /* If we reach last index every time the penultimate index is updated to it's corresponding consecutive index (successor).*/
{
    u=0;
    while(a[u]!=-1)
    u++;


    a[u-2]=indexSearcher(a,main_a,a[u-2],n);//gives the successor of the penultimate index
    a[u-1]=-1;
    for (j=0;j<=u-2;j++){
        printf("%d ",a[j]);
    }
     u=0;
    while(a[u]!=-1)
    u++;
    //printer(a,i-1);
    printf("\n");
}

else if(a[u-1]!=main_a[n-1])
  /*If we don't reach the last index we print until we get there every time in a  new line by updating the index by 1 */
{
    u=0;
    while(a[u]!=-1)
    u++;
    a[u]=indexSearcher(a,main_a,a[u-1],n);/*here we get the correct lexical value
      i.e., the element which should come after the current element in lexical order.*/
    a[u+1]=-1;
    for (j=0;j<u+1;j++){
        printf("%d ",a[j]);
    }
     u=0;
    while(a[u]!=-1)
    u++;

    printf("\n");
}
}

}

int indexSearcher(int a[],int main_a[],int s,int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(s==main_a[i]){
    return main_a[i+1];
    }
    }
    return 0; 
}
```